# No boot-args in nvram

Tags: macos, osx-server, nvram

After seeing [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264958/what-does-serverperfmode-1-actually-do-on-macos) regarding the serverperfmode nvram boot-arg, I thought I would check my server to see its status:

```
$ nvram boot-args
nvram: Error getting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) data was not found
```

Is this a normal response (i.e., if no boot-args have been set), or is something out of whack with my server.  Apple's [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202528) doesn't mention the error.

My server is a Mac Pro running 10.11.6, off of a internal SSD.  And, Server.app is installed/configured.

Output of `nvram -p` shows the following variables:

```
efi-boot-device
bluetoothInternalControllerInfo
fmm-computer-name
efi-apple-recovery
SystemAudioVolumeDB
bluetoothActiveControllerInfo
SystemAudioVolume
eft-boot-device-data
BootCampProcessorPstates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the normal response if the variable has not been set.
Example commands and output along your line of inquiry:

```
$ nvram boot-args
  boot-args serverperfmode=1 -v
```

Whereas:

```
$ nvram bootargs        # missing character results in: non existing variable
  nvram: Error getting variable - 'bootargs': (iokit/common) data was not found
```

This is the same state for this variable you get after deleting the whole variable or after clearing all variables with an NVRAM reset.

And if `nvram -p` does show nothing but what you posted then such a procedure was quite recent.

To test for 'normality':

```
$ nvram -p                        # print all nvram variables
boot-args serverperfmode 1 -v     # output if only boot-args is set
$ sudo nvram -d boot-args         # delete nvram variable for boot-args
$ nvram -p                        # print all nvram variables
                                  # nothing to output
$ nvram boot-args                 # try to read only boot-args variable 
nvram: Error getting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) data was not found # your error message
$ sudo nvram boot-args="-v"       # set boot-args to verbose boot mode
$ nvram -p                        # print all nvram variables
boot-args -v                      # output for nvram variable boot-args shown
$ nvram boot-args                 # print only boot-args nvram variable
boot-args -v
```

Comment: might want to mention that setting a new boot-arg overwrites old boot-args, ie. adding a new boot-arg does not append to the current list but rather creates a new one thus deleting all prior args

Answer (score -1):

I use the following to enable verbose boot: (may need to disable system protection)

```
#!/bin/bash
nvram -p
echo "Enabling Verbose Boot Now..."
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
nvram -p
```

Only the sudo lineis need the others are to monitor the change.

Comment: Not sure this explains why the OP does get an error.