# How can I increase the number of maximum processes on MacBook Pro M1 chip

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, java, apple-silicon

Whenever I am running more than 4000 threads, a testing application(jmeter) throws `Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.`

There is an upper cap of 4000 on the number of maximum processes on macBook Pro M1 which I found using `sudo launchctl limit maxproc`.

Response of given cmd: `maxproc     2666           4000`

I have a RAM of 16GB. Can anyone suggest how can I increase the max processes.

Comment: Processes and threads are different things usually, also the exception thrown is an out of memory exception so  I'm not sure increasing the possible number of processes will help you here.

Comment: My guess is that they are related. If you know how to increase the max process then please let me know

Comment: Did you verify that you don't actually run out of memory? Keeping Activity Monitor running while you test your application might help here.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373063/why-is-macos-limited-to-1064-or-2088-processes